# java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.addNotes) must not be null

Tags: android

I have started to develop an application somehow i got an error in MainActivity.java class and i couldn't identify please help me.Thanks in advance

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var addNotes: FloatingActionButton
private lateinit var notesRV: RecyclerView
private lateinit var notesList: ArrayList<Notes>
private lateinit var realm: Realm

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val todayFragment = TodayFragment()
    val fragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TodayFragment::class.java.simpleName)

    if (fragment !is TodayFragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, todayFragment, TodayFragment::class.java.simpleName)
            .commit()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to NoteActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    //        init views
    addNotes = findViewById(R.id.addNotes)
    notesRV = findViewById(R.id.notesRV)
    //        onclick add notes btn
    addNotes.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this, AddNotesActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    notesRV.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
    getAllNotes()
}

private fun getAllNotes() {
    notesList.clear()
    notesList = ArrayList()

    val result: RealmResults<Notes> = realm.where<Notes>(Notes::class.java).findAll()

    notesRV.adapter = NotesAdapter(this, result)
    notesRV.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

fragment note.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".NoteFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notesRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_write_white_create_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_background"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my logcat

> 2020-10-19 15:07:58.580 24447-24447/com.d3ifcool.notivity
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.d3ifcool.notivity, PID: 24447
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d3ifcool.notivity/com.d3ifcool.notivity.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.addNotes) must not
> be null
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3488)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.addNotes) must not be null
> at com.d3ifcool.notivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3463)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

Help me please

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> findViewById(R.id.addNotes) must not be null
> at com.d3ifcool.notivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)

Comment: Because `R.id.addNotes` is in `fragment note.xml` not in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Also, `findViewById` may return `null`, so perhaps use `RecyclerView?` rather than `RecyclerView` as type?

Comment: R.id.addnotes probably is not in the R.layout.activity_main, so you can only reference to your id from your loaded view.  If R.id.addnotes is in the fragment layout, you must do the findViewById in your onCreateView fragment, not in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using kotlin, You really no need findViewById method as we can directly use xml ids to activity.

Remove below lines from activity

```
 private lateinit var addNotes: FloatingActionButton
 private lateinit var notesRV: RecyclerView

 addNotes = findViewById(R.id.addNotes)
 notesRV = findViewById(R.id.notesRV)
```

Comment: your code is work but still problem with

addNotes.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, AddNotesActivity::class.java))
        }

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: it is because you are setting content view for layout activity_main and calling id is in fragment layout.

Comment: You can call views that exist in current activity’s xml only.